# Synchronization of threads

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

I have a simple program you'll find below. The question is whether the two threads can run parallel given the following settings: 
1. One core processor,
2. Two core processor,
3. Two one core processors. 
Does this program have the risk of Race Competition?

This is what I've found so far:
1. One core processor - technically threads are not running in parallel, they only appear so, as the CPU switches between them very fast.
2. Two core processor - the number of threads that can run in parallel (simultaneously) is equal to the number of cores, therefore yes, in this case 2 threads can run in parallel.
3. Two one core processors ??

L1: Global

```
int t1_next=1;
int t2_next=0;
```

L2: Thread 1

```
while(1) {
  if(t1_next){
    printf("a");
    printf("b");
    printf("c");
    printf("d");
t1_next=0;
t2_next=1;}
else sleep(10);
}
```

L3: Thread 2

```
while(1) {
  if(t2_next){
    printf("e");
    printf("f");
    printf("g");
    printf("h");
t1_next=1;
t2_next=0;}
else sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: case: 1) your program works ok, no race conditions; 2) problem of race conditions; 3) since the OS can schedule each thread independently i think that you may suffer from race conditions if at the same time thread1 is run on core1 of processor1 and thread2 is run on core2 of processor2 or vice versa.

Comment: In case 1) since the CPU is switching from on thread to the other, couldn't it be that the order of the output is also incorrect?

Comment: No it couldn't because also if the OS preempt one thread and execute the other with your if cycle the thread is going to sleep for 10 second and so the OS will reschedule the initial thread. This behavior will go on until thread1 (or thread2) will finish printing and will set the t1_next and t2_next variable's value.

Comment: "core" is a term from semiconductor manufacturing. From programmer's point of view, core is a processor, and "Two core processor" equals to "Two one core processors".